# What should I use as the return statement?

Tags: java

I am creating a method called `swapElements()`. It takes an array of integers, and two integer indexes. The method should swap the values of the array elements with the specified indexes.

```
public class{
  int swapElements(int[] number, int value1, int value2){
        int temp = number[value1];
        number[value1] = number[value2];
        number[value2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to return anything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Smells like homework to me.

Comment: could easily throw an exception.

Comment: You could at least take the time to paraphrase your homework question instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: It must be homework.  The OP apparently does not know of the distinction between arguments passed by reference and those passed by value (the value of a reference type is still a reference).

Comment: The code does not compile because the class does not have a name.

Comment: I believe you should use an IDE and google any error you get there, most of them are easy to understand. IE this one, `Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected after this token` It means you don't have a class name. After fixing it, my IDE says this: `This method must return a result of type int`, read answers below.

Answer (score 3):

As you have presented it, this method does not need to return anything, and should probably be declared `void`.  However, if there is a specific contract it needs to fulfill then you should return whatever the interface definition says it should return.

Answer (score 2):

There are four things wrong with your code.

1. The thing you're asking about: use `return number;`, because you want to return the array with swapped elements.
2. Make the method return an `int[]` (like `int[] swapElements`), not an `int`.
3. Your class has no name. You need to add a name, like `public class IntArraySwapper { ...`.
4. Your method should be `static`. Without using that keyword, you must call it on an instance, like `new IntArraySwapper().swapElements(...)`. Since this method has nothing to do with class instances, simply make it static (`static int[] swapElements`) so that you can call it like `IntArraySwapper.swapElements(...)`.

Note that the method will also modify the original array, so techinically you don't *need* to return anything. If you want, you could just make it a `void` method and use the old array.

Comment: The fourth thing wrong is that this method has no dependence at all on any state of an object, and yet the method is an instance method.  It should be a static method.

Answer (score 2):

you can just make it return void.
or maybe a boolean to indicate that the sawp happened, with no errors.
like index out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases the `return` type is not strictly required. So, you should return `void`. But if you indeed want to return something, consider returning `boolean` to specify if the swap happened or not. More precisely you can include the swap code into `try catch` block which returns `True` if the swap happened without any error and `False` otherwise.